# Python to SQL using strip

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, strip

gday I would like to know how to convert the following python script to sql and with its source file being a txt file

```
Data = [
            r[0: 2].strip(),        # Column 1
            r[2: 14].strip()        # Column 2
       ]
```

I've loaded the txt file into a table with a single column called TableA

```
   TRIM(SUBSTRING(TableA.Col, 0, 2)) AS Column1
  ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(TableA.Col, 2, 14)) AS Column2
```

but it doesnt look right - could someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Also what "doesnt look right" means exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `r` is a string, then slicing syntax is `[start:stop:step]`. Then `r[0:2]` would mean start=0, stop=2 and index 2 is not included

`SUBSTRING` syntax is `SUBSTRING(string, start, length)` and first index is 1.

So

`r[0: 2]` --> `SUBSTRING(TableA.Col, 1, 2)`

`r[2: 14]` --> `SUBSTRING(TableA.Col, 3, 12)`